# AOC USB monitor showing dark screen after installing DisplayLink driver

Tags: 14.04, drivers, multiple-monitors, displaylink

I connected an AOC usb monitor to my Acer Aspire laptop which is using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I then installed the DisplayLink driver. Unfortunately, the AOC monitor remains dark. Any ideas how to troubleshoot this ?

**Informations about my system**

1) Monitor: AOC usb monitor e1649Fwu

2) Laptop: Acer Aspire E 15 - ES1-511-C723 - Intel Celeron Processor N2830

3) DisplayLink Driver: http://www.displaylink.com/downloads/ubuntu.php (available since August 3rd, 2015, quite recent when I posted this message).

4) Ubuntu & Linux Version:

```
uname -a
Linux MYCOMPUTER 3.16.0-45-generic #60~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 24 21:16:23 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**Some more observations**

1) The AOC usb monitor has 2 usb connectors. One is plugged in a laptop USB 3.0 socket and the other in a usb 2.0 socket.

2) When I plug in the AOC monitor or on computer boot, the AOC monitor flashes for a fraction of a second, then remains dark.

3) When I move the cursor to the right limit of my laptop main monitor, the cursor disappears and jumps into the usb monitor space (yet I cannot see it because the usb monitor is dark).

4) The AOC usb monitor is somehow detected by Ubunty (Device 011 below)

```
lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04f2:b47f Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 093a:2510 Pixart Imaging, Inc. Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 04ca:300b Lite-On Technology Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. USB-2.0 4-Port HUB
Bus 001 Device 011: ID 17e9:4107 DisplayLink 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

5) When the AOC screen is connected, the mouse on my main monitor flashes really fast and sometimes disappears.

6) When I do a print screen, Ubuntu captures images from two monitors (see images below).

7) In Systems Settings -> Screen Display, the AOC monitor shows as FNM 0" (images below contain the screen display data of both the main laptop monitor and AOC monitor).

[image: Screen Display - AOC Monitor (print screen sees 2 screens !)]

[image: Screen Display - Main Monitor (print screen sees 2 screens !)]

Any ideas how to troubleshoot this ?

Comment: Interesting. The firmware build number is a bit lower than the latest Windows 10 driver, but I will check if I can get my device to work with 14.04 when I'm back home.

Comment: Just checked. Sorry no problems I can reproduce here with my HP 3005pr, it just added a 2nd monitor with the correct resolution after the driver installation finished (too easy and too fast compared to Windows, I thought that day would never happen). So this must an issue with your device or settings in Ubuntu. You could try installing the latest Windows driver and make sure that it updates your device with the newest firmware.

Comment: I'm having the same problem but with Ubuntu 16.04. Were you able to solve it?